# DateTime.ToString() format that can be used in a filename or extension?

Tags: c#, datetime, filenames, datetime-format

I want to add a timestamp to filenames as files are created but most of the DateTime methods I've tried output something with spaces and slashes. For instance:

```
Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString()); // <-- 9/19/2012 1:41:46 PM
Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()); // <-- 1:41 PM
Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()); // <-- 9/19/2012
Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToFileTime()); // <-- 129925501061462806
```

`ToFileTime()` works but is not exactly human-readable. How can I format the output to a human-readable timestamp with date and time that can be used in a filename or extension? Prefereably something like `2011-19-9--13-45-30`?

Comment: How about this...DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd--hh-mm-ss")

Answer (score 216, accepted):

You can use this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-M--HH-mm-ss");
```

Comment: You have a look at more examples/options here: http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm

Comment: I guess considering utc time would be better

Comment: Are you seriously suggesting to have the day between the year and month??

Comment: Even more inexcusable in a filename since the list of files cannot be sorted by name to get them in date time order. Most-significant to least significant should be the order of the day.

Comment: @Bernhard Hofmann, you can sort the file names by created/modified attributes if you care so much about that.

Comment: @Matt -  you assume the filename is related to the created/modified/accessed date which it isn't always.

Comment: @Bernhard Hofmann, I was referring to the created/modified metadata stored for the file in the file system, not the file name itself: https://imgur.com/a/5xSAnbX

Comment: @Matt And now take that file, copy it to a USB stick to transfer somewhere else and then check that metadata again (apart from the obvious problem that Bernhard is talking about: You might create a file for a date other than "right now"). It's just incredibly stupid to have this as the highest upvoted and accepted answer.

Comment: So we found our way here after discovering that a third-party pod running in our Kubernetes cluster was constantly writing files named e.g. `2022-31-1--13-37-42.txt` until disk space ran out. We concluded that such an, um, unorthodox date format simply _had_ to be explicitly specified in the source code of the pod, and sure enough: the culprit line used the exact expression above. Turns out this answer is the top result on Google for `date format file name dotnet` and similar queries, so if it was submitted as a honeypot to expose copy-paste programming, then well played!

Answer (score 181):

I would use the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, without separators:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmss")
```

Comment: If you use `DateTime.Now.ToString("o")`, it will give you `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff-HH:mm` (where the final hour and minute offset are +/- GMT). Granted, this wouldn't work as a filename format, but the `"o"` formatting is good to know.

Comment: This can also be written as `$"{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMddTHHmmss}"` using string interpolation.

Comment: [RFC 3339](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339#section-5.6) Says that you should retain the dashes for date. `DateTime.Now.ToString("s").Replace(":", "")`

Comment: @HackSlash Good to know. This question, however, is about file names where we often need to consider illegal characters. `:` is often such a character (while `-` often is not). Then it becomes a question of whether to always use separators (possibly introducing illegal characters), use separators where possible (not compliant to standards) or skip separators completely (compliant). This answer clearly is in favor of the latter.

Comment: @HackSlash Removing only the `:` will most likely result in a timestamp that is neither ISO8601 nor RFC3339 compliant.

Answer (score 29):

I have a similar situation but I want a consistent way to be able to use `DateTime.Parse` from the filename as well, so I went with

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("s").Replace(":", ".") // <-- 2016-10-25T16.50.35
```

When I want to parse, I can simply reverse the Replace call.  This way I don't have to type in any yymmdd stuff or guess what formats DateTime.Parse allows.

Comment: Standard, simple, sortable, virtually unique (due to sub second precision), elegant - easily beats all the other answers.

Answer (score 14):

Personally I like it this way:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss")
```

Because it distinguishes between the date and the time.

Comment: I guess you mean "yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss"

Comment: While this is valid, having spaces in file names/paths is generally not best, as it can introduce problems in software that doesn't account for that, and paths in the command line that don't contain quotes. Having an underscore or two dashes is better practice.

Comment: @NoahHeber They really do not, except you are using Linux. Where everybody harps how great their OS is and how bullshit windows is. Except every second script or program  cannot work with freaking spaces in a path.  
I rather like my spaces in a path, at least I value it more than the ability to write a file named COM1

Answer (score 11):

The below list of time format specifiers most commonly used.,

> ***dd*** -- ***day*** of the month, from 01 through 31.
>
> ***MM*** -- ***month***, from 01 through 12.
>
> ***yyyy*** -- ***year*** as a four-digit number.
>
> ***hh*** -- ***hour***, using a **12-hour** clock from 01 to 12.
>
> ***mm*** -- ***minute***, from 00 through 59.
>
> ***ss*** -- ***second***, from 00 through 59.
>
> ***HH*** -- ***hour***, using a **24-hour** clock from 00 to 23.
>
> ***tt*** -- ***AM/PM*** designator.

Using the above you will be able to form a unique name to your file name.

***Here i have provided example***

```
string fileName = "fileName_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm-ss-tt") + ".pdf";
```

***OR***

If you don't prefer to use symbols you can try this also.,

```
string fileName = "fileName_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyyhhmmsstt") + ".pdf";
```

Hope this helps to someone now or in future. :)

Comment: I would prefer using string interpolation: `var fileName = $"fileName_{DateTime.Now:MMddyyyyhhmmsstt}.pdf";`

Answer (score 8):

Using [interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) string & [format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format):

```
var filename = $"{DateTime.Now:yyyy.dd.M HH-mm-ss}"
```

Example Output for January 1st, 2020 at 10:40:45AM:

> 2020.28.01 10-40-45

---

Or if you want a standard date format:

```
var filename = $"{DateTime.Now:yyyy.M.dd HH-mm-ss}"
```

> 2020.01.28 10-40-45

---

*Note: this feature is available in C# 6 and later versions of the language.*

Comment: year-day-month is not a valid date format/order. There is only one date standard that starts with the year, and it's year-month-day order. month-day-year is OK in the US, but day-month-year isn't universal everywhere outside of the US either.

Comment: @JeremyBell year-day-month is used because the question specifically asks for that format, "_Prefereably something like 2011-19-9--13-45-30_"

Answer (score 6):

You can try with

```
var result = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-d--HH-mm-ss");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make a path for your file as bellow:

```
string path = "fileName-"+DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-M--HH-mm-ss") + ".txt";
```