# How to get colons in filenames using content-disposition?

Tags: escaping, character, content-disposition

How do I get a file name to include special characters like ':'?

I need to include a timestamp in my file name in this format: `12:00 PM`. Using content-Disposition I am getting 12_00PM.

Comment: Some operating systems won't accept : in the filename.

Comment: Is the fact that Windows disallows the colon character in filenames a deal-breaker for you?  Are you attached to the format?  Because you could [choose a more appropriate format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12500091/1563833).

Comment: Without the OS used, impossible to answer.

Comment: The file name should be in the format xyz_02122018_4:25PM.xlsx but with content-disposition the colon in the timestamp is replaced with underscore

Comment: I am using windows

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't, due to security and interoperability considerations. See https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc6266.html#rfc.section.4.3.