# How to Create a Text Filename with DateTime using C#

Tags: c#, file, datetime, filestream

I want to create a Filename with DateTime.Now to store the errors that catched using Exception Handling everyday.

I used `DateTime.ToFileTime`, but the format appending for not in date format.

```
string result = "myFile_" + DateTime.Now.ToFileTime() + ".txt";
string path = "E:\\ErrorCollector\\ErrorCollector" + DateTime.Now.ToFileTime()+ ".txt";

FileStream fi = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter(fi);
sw1.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + "" + ex.message);
```

I am Expecting the filename like "ErrorCollector17/08/2019"

Comment: What format do you want to get exactly? How about using custom formatting instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500091/datetime-tostring-format-that-can-be-used-in-a-filename-or-extension

Comment: If i use the above code, My file is created like "ErrorCollector132097177851536974" , I wish it should be created with (dd/MM/yyyy) format.

Comment: @AshwinKumar This is _how_ `ToFileTime` works. It would be better to read it's documentation before using any functionality when you writing code. In your case, you can use `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` for example to generate a custom formatted string. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: As another suggestion, yyyyMMdd format is generally preferred because if you sort the the files in a folder by name, the most recent one is on the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `ToString` function with a format.

```
 DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy",new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jqXHMZ)

As Soundararajan say I would suggest you use

```
"ddMMyyyy"
```

or

```
"dd-MM-yyyy"
```

due to the system will confuse your path contain `\`

Comment: / is a path separating character in unix based systems (Linux / Mac). So it might not be a good option to have as part of filename. Suggest that you replace it with an allowed character for filenames (e.x -)

Comment: ThankYou Sir, Its Working.

Answer (score 3):

You are not allowed to create filename which contains any of following characters: /:*?"<>| on Windows, you can do like this

```
string path = "E:\\ErrorCollector\\ErrorCollector" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")+ ".txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

shortest answer would be the code below:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

`DateTime.Now` gets the current date and time based on your computer's clock.

`.ToString(...)` converts the DateTime object into a string with optional formatting inside as parameters.

`"yyyyMMddHHmmss"` is a pattern for how you want the DateTime object be mapped in a string manner where. assuming your computer's clock is currently ticked at "August 8, 2019 12:34:56 PM", then:

- yyyy = is a 4 digit year as 2019
- MM = is a 2 digit month equivalent such as 08
- dd = is a 2 digit day of the year such as 08
- HH = is a 2 digit hour equivalent in 24 Hours format such as 12
- mm = is a 2 digit minute such as 34
- ss = is a 2 digit second such as 56

and the output would be `20190808123456`. Note that the arrangement of year, month, date, hour, minute, or even second can be in no specific order.

`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is used if you are formatting or parsing a string that should be parseable by a piece of software independent of the user's local settings (via [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9760339/7825830))

note that we removed special characters separating different parts of the DateTime object to prevent issues when filenames on Windows.